# What is the difference between creating a table on partition scheme versus creating a cluster index on partition scheme

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

To achieve partitioning, you can create a table on a partition scheme or create the table on primary followed by adding a clustered index on the partition scheme.  Is there any difference/preference between the two approaches?  They both seems to achieve the same set of partitions when querying system partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any difference/preference between the two approaches?

A Clustered Index *is* the table, so no, there is no difference.  When you create a clustered index, either directly or through a Primary Key Constraint you are re-creating the table, and moving it to the partition scheme.

The only observable difference I can think of is if you start with a table on a filegroup, add some non-clustered indexes, and then add a partitioned clustered indexes, the non-clustered indexes will remain on the filegroup, not on the partition scheme.